# webpack 2 dynamic import files from directories

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

I have a react application with dir structure:

```
app
|\widgets
|  |
|  |\Widget1
|  | \reducers\index.js
|  |\anotherFolder\index.js
|  |
|  |\Widget2
|  |\reducers\index.js
|  |\anotherFolder\index.js
|  
|
\mainreducers/index.js
```

i need some how import all widget-x/reducers/index.js into mainreducers/index.js.
Currently I'm trying with:

```
const req = require.context("../widgets/", true, /index.js/);
function requireAll(requireContext) {
   return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}
const modules = requireAll(req);
```

but this imports me also other index.js from anotherFolder (another solution that i did find is to rename index.js (widgetX/reducer/) name to reduces.js and use the require.context  but that's is not how i need it).

Thanks.